# NameError: uninitialized constant when trying to execute rails tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, testunit, ruby-2.0

In a Rails 3.2.13 app I'm writing right now I have a model called `Business`. As this model was getting fatter and fatter, I decided to split it up in two, extracting all code related to availability into a Rails concern named `Availability`, stored at `models/concerns/business`

```
class Business
  module Availability
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    AVAILABILITY_OPEN        =  1
    AVAILABILITY_CLOSED      = -1
    AVAILABILITY_COMPLETE    = -2

...
```

As concerns are not enabled in Rails by default, I've put the following line in `config/application.rb` in order to autoload them:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/models/concerns)
```

The problem is that, after the split, all my tests have stopped working, returning a `NameError: uninitialized constant Availability` error. I suppose I need to require this concern somehow in my tests, but I haven't managed to do it yet, and I also don't understand why this concern is needed even in tests which doesn't make use of it.

The following is the stack trace returned after running the tests:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Availability
    (erb):9:in `<main>'
    /home/sergio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/erb.rb:849:in `eval'
    /home/sergio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/erb.rb:849:in `result'
    /home/sergio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/fixtures/file.rb:51:in `render'
    /home/sergio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/fixtures/file.rb:43:in `rows'
    /home/sergio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/fixtures/file.rb:29:in `each'
    /home/sergio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:670:in `block (2 levels) in read_fixture_files'
    /home/sergio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/fixtures/file.rb:20:in `open'
    /home/sergio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:669:in `block in read_fixture_files'
    /home/sergio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:668:in `each'
    /home/sergio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:668:in `read_fixture_files'
    /home/sergio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:548:in `initialize'
    /home/sergio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:482:in `new'
    /home/sergio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:482:in `block (2 levels) in create_fixtures'
    /home/sergio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:479:in `map'
    /home/sergio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:479:in `block in create_fixtures'
    /home/sergio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:232:in `disable_referential_integrity'
    /home/sergio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:476:in `create_fixtures'
    /home/sergio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:895:in `load_fixtures'
    /home/sergio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:849:in `setup_fixtures'
    /home/sergio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:407:in `_run__871072887135343583__setup__3260066542044458782__callbacks'
    /home/sergio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
    /home/sergio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_setup_callbacks'
    /home/sergio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    /home/sergio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:35:in `run'
    /home/sergio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:919:in `block in _run_suite'
    /home/sergio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:912:in `map'
    /home/sergio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:912:in `_run_suite'
    /home/sergio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit.rb:657:in `block in _run_suites'
    /home/sergio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit.rb:655:in `each'
    /home/sergio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit.rb:655:in `_run_suites'
    /home/sergio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:867:in `_run_anything'
    /home/sergio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:1060:in `run_tests'
    /home/sergio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:1047:in `block in _run'
    /home/sergio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:1046:in `each'
    /home/sergio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:1046:in `_run'
    /home/sergio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:1035:in `run'
    /home/sergio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit.rb:21:in `run'
    /home/sergio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit.rb:774:in `run'
    /home/sergio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit.rb:366:in `block (2 levels) in autorun'
    /home/sergio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit.rb:27:in `run_once'
    /home/sergio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit.rb:365:in `block in autorun'
```

**UPDATE**

This is an excerpt of the class `Business`, which includes the `Availability` concern:

```
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Availability
  include EmailVirtualAttribute
  include TelephoneVirtualAttribute

  belongs_to :place
  has_many :businesses_users
  has_many :users,        :through => :businesses_users, :uniq => true
  has_many :customers,    :inverse_of => :business, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :emails,       :as => :contactable, :class_name => 'Email'
  has_many :telephones,   :as => :contactable, :class_name => 'Telephone'

  ...
```

The development/test configs are the standard ones, no changes have been made

**test.rb**

```
Rendezvous::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # The test environment is used exclusively to run your application's
  # test suite. You never need to work with it otherwise. Remember that
  # your test database is "scratch space" for the test suite and is wiped
  # and recreated between test runs. Don't rely on the data there!
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Configure static asset server for tests with Cache-Control for performance
  config.serve_static_assets = true
  config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=3600"

  # Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil
  config.whiny_nils = true

  # Show full error reports and disable caching
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Raise exceptions instead of rendering exception templates
  config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = false

  # Disable request forgery protection in test environment
  config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection    = false

  # Tell Action Mailer not to deliver emails to the real world.
  # The :test delivery method accumulates sent emails in the
  # ActionMailer::Base.deliveries array.
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test

  # Raise exception on mass assignment protection for Active Record models
  config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict

  # Print deprecation notices to the stderr
  config.active_support.deprecation = :stderr
end
```

**development.rb**

```
Rendezvous::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil.
  config.whiny_nils = true

  # Show full error reports and disable caching
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Only use best-standards-support built into browsers
  config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin

  # Raise exception on mass assignment protection for Active Record models
  config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict

  # Log the query plan for queries taking more than this (works
  # with SQLite, MySQL, and PostgreSQL)
  config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5

  # Do not compress assets
  config.assets.compress = false

  # Expands the lines which load the assets
  config.assets.debug = true
end
```

**UPDATE 2**

It seems that the errors that happen when executing the tests are caused by the fixtures. If  I comment the `fixtures :all` loading on `test_helper.rb` and create a simple test that just asserts true, this test pass, but it doesn't when the fixtures are loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the reason why all my tests failed with an error. I was referencing to a constant declared in the `Availability` concern using `Availabiliy::` , instead of using `Business::`. Also, my tests were not in sync with the current code, which made finding the bug a lot more difficult than it should. Replacing all the references to `Availability` with `Business` solved the problem. The lesson here is: **keep always application and testing code in sync**.

Thank you to Lichtamberg for all his kind support.

Answer (score 1):

Try it with the specific model name.. like User::Confirmation

```
# -*- encoding : utf-8 -*-
require 'active_support/concern'

module Business::Availability
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
```

And this:

```
config.autoload_paths += Rails.root.join("app", "models", "concerns")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Lichtamberg, unfortunately it keeps returning the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: Lichtamberg, I've updated the question with the relevant part of the `business` class. Tell me if you need something more.

Comment: I think you meant `config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join("app", "models", "concerns")]`. Anyway, this doesn't work either, returns the same error. Note that my current code works in the application, it's only when testing that this error appears.

Comment: ah ok, yeah, please post your developmetn/test configs

Comment: I've updated the question with the data you asked for. Thank you!

Comment: Does this happen to all tests or just to a specific?

Comment: this happen to all tests

Answer (score 0):

I've kind of isolated the source of the problem, which are the fixtures. I was using the `fixtures :all` method in `test_helper.rb`. Changing it to just run the `customers.yml` fixture, I'm able to run `customer_test.rb` with no errors. What I don't know yet what are the offending fixtures (I suppose that `businesses.yml` and maybe related ones, but I've not checked it) and why are causing the problem.